# Disabling RAID for home PC

Tags: linux, raid, gparted

I inherited decommissioned server HDDs from work.  I plugged both into my PC at home, but it looks like they're both enabled for RAID, as I can't unlink them in GParted to use as separate storages.

Is there a way for me to turn off the RAID between these two HDDs without having their original server?  I tried to format one with ext4 and the other with NTFS, but even that doesn't seem to be separating them.

In this screenshot, `/dev/sda/` is my first HDD and `/dev/sdb/` is my second HDD.

[image: What I see in GParted]

Comment: In GParted > Devices > New partition table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAID status is just metadata stored on the disk, much like partitions or filesystems or LVMs, and can be erased in the same way.

Linux has two programs which recognize different RAID metadata formats: *dmraid* (part of device-mapper) and *mdadm* (does its own thing).

1. Your RAID volume is under "/dev/mapper", which means it has been assembled through device-mapper. Use either `dmraid -an` or `dmsetup remove <device>` to temporarily deactivate it:

   ```
   dmsetup remove ddf1_Backups1
   ```

   For /dev/md names the command would be `mdadm --stop <device>`.
2. Then use `wipefs` or similar to clear all metadata (RAIDs, partition tables, and so on) and prevent the RAID setup from being recognized in the future:

   ```
   wipefs --all /dev/sda
   wipefs --all /dev/sdb
   ```

   (You can also zero out the beginning and/or end of both disks, but wipefs does its job faster.)
3. Finally create regular partition tables using GParted, `fdisk`, or `gdisk`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete and recreate the partitions.  This should wipe any RAID configuration from them.

I've never done this for LVM, but it works for Windows software RAID.

Comment: With DDF (and often Linux lvm/mdraid), the partitions usually go on top of RAID.